# Live Camera App with Qt

Tags: camera, qt

I am trying to write an application using Qt that displays live video from the Pi camera. The Qt example projects ["camera"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html) (using QWidgets) and "declarative-camera" (using QML) both run without generating any errors, and each actually detects that the camera is there, but in each case the camera display portion is just black. Additionally, in the first example, the "Capture Photo" button is greyed out and clicking trying to record a video yields the error "Service has not been started". Running `raspistill` works. Is it possible to use Qt components to access the camera, or do I have to use an API specifically designed for the Raspberry Pi?

[image: Qt camera example program with black camera area]